# JavaFX listen to hokeys

Tags: javafx, hotkeys

Does anyone know how i cant listen to global hotkeys in javaFX?

i found a library for normal java but i cant get it to work with javafx.

I can get it to work on a normal java project but. When i use it in a javafx project i get the following error

```
    jfx-project-run:
Executing D:\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MPDClient\dist\run1477960237\MPDClient.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
    at com.tulskiy.keymaster.common.Provider.getCurrentProvider(Provider.java:52)
    at mpdclient.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:173)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2193)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
    at mpdclient.MPDClient.start(MPDClient.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 21 more
```

Link to the [Libray](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jna` library in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this in pom.xml